# Python lxml iterparse to create full tree

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using the requests package and lxml.
With requests I get a response from a server which contains huge xml data.
To process the data in other parts of my programm I would like to create a ElementTree Object with all nodes.

If I use etree.fromstring, a huge part of the xml is missing.

If I write the data to a file like in my code below, the file contains all elements.

```
self.response_code = response.status_code
        if response.ok:
            missing = self.response_code = response.status_code

        if response.ok:

            missing = etree.fromstring(response.content)

            response.raw.decode_content = True      
            with open('temp.xml', 'wb') as file_handle:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
                    if chunk:
                        file_handle.write(chunk)
                        fule_handle.flush()

            events = etree.iterparse('temp.xml', huge_tree=True, events=('end'), encoding='utf-8')

            for event, elem in events:

                if event == 'end':
                    print(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True))
```

Best regards

h0mebrewer

Comment: a) What does "huge" mean, in numbers? b) If you want a full tree in the end anyway, there is literally no advantage in using progressive parsing. c) You are writing the file in 512 byte chunks, from a *full XML string* that you already have in memory before you even start writing, and after you're done writing all of it to file, you start reading it again. All of this seems to be a whole lot of pointless busywork to me. What's your goal, or the other way around, what is the thing you're trying to avoid with this?

Comment: a) Huge means 51k lines c) it seems that the full xml string is not available at this point. If I try to use .findall not all elements which I expect are given. The file contains all expected elements. I'm trying to avoid, that some data is lost.

Comment: Hmm... a) "Lines" is not a very useful measurement in XML. What's the file size? Megabytes? Gigabytes? Anything up to a couple hundred MB can be handled by an in-memory tree. c) When `requests` (I suppose you're using `requests` here, right?) is done, and you're accessing `response.content` then you *definitely* are not missing any data (unless the server's response was not complete to begin with).